# Show/hide textarea when other radio selected - jQuery Event Not Being Fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm trying to hide a `textarea` if the `other` option isn't selected. I'm not getting any errors so I guess the syntax is correct but the event listener I guess is incorrect. I've tried `focus()` in place of the `click()` as well because I thought maybe the `input` wouldn't register as a `click`. Neither of these have worked though.

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="when" value="time" />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="when" value="count" />
    <br />
    Other:
    <input type="radio" name="when" value="other" />
    <br />
    <textarea name="when_other"></textarea>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='when']").click(function() {
        if($("input[name='when']").value == 'other'){
            $("text[name='when_other']").attr('display', 'block');
        } else {
            $("text[name='when_other']").attr('display', 'none');
            $("text[name='when_other']").html('');
        }
    });
</script>
```

The above also is the order the mark up appears, HTML first, JS trailing. There is no dynamic content on the page either, so `live()`/`on()` I don't think are required.

Comment: just for clear understanding ..you want to hide the textarea if radiobutton 'when' is selected ..right

Comment: If `<input type="radio" name="when" value="other" />` is selected the `textarea` should display. If `<input type="radio" name="when" value="time" />` or `<input type="radio" name="when" value="count" />` are selected it should not display.

Comment: added answer for it just check and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some small mistakes, compare this one:

```css
textarea {display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input type="radio" name="when" value="time" />
<br />
<input type="radio" name="when" value="count" />
<br />
Other:
<input type="radio" name="when" value="other" />
<br />
<textarea name="when_other"></textarea>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("body").on("click","input[name='when']",function() {
    if($("input[name='when']:checked").val()== 'other'){
        $("textarea[name='when_other']").css('display', 'block');
    } else {
        $("textarea[name='when_other']").css('display', 'none');
        $("textarea[name='when_other']").val('');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Can you explain about the required `on` here?

Comment: You can use normal event also `$().click(function...`. i Just attach click event using `on`☺️

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript,just do like this,this will fix your problem

```
var $selectAll = $( "input:radio[name=when]" );
$selectAll.on( "change", function() {
if($("input[name='when']:checked").val() != "other")
{ 
  $("#when_other").hide();
}
else{
 $("#when_other").show();
  }
}
```

and in your html, add id to your textarea like this

```
<textarea id="when_other" name="when_other"></textarea>
```

Comment: Do I need this in the `click` still or on its own? `$("textarea[name='when_other']")` should work the same as the `id` as well, no?

Comment: yes..it will work in the same click event,,have you tried with above code

Comment: Yes, it didnt function though.

Comment: @user3783243, try onchange event of radio button ,it will work

Comment: I've tried this approach as well but it hasn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using `this` in jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  $('input[name ="when"]').click(function() {
    $("textarea").show();

    if ($(this).val() == "other")
      $("textarea").show();
    else
      $("textarea").hide();
  })
});

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="when" value="time" />
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="when" value="count" />
  <br /> Other:
  <input type="radio" id="show_other" name="when" value="other" />
  <br />
  <textarea name="when_other"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a Toggle?

```js
$(":input[name='when']").on("change", function () {
  $("textarea[name='when_other']").toggle(this.value === 'other' && this.checked);
//alert('click');
}).change();
```

```css
textarea {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <input type="radio" name="when" value="time" />
    <br />
    <input type="radio" name="when" value="count" />
    <br />
    Other:
    <input type="radio" name="when" value="other" />
    <br />
    <textarea name="when_other"></textarea>
</div>
```